# PyQt: QTableWidget get selected row number

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I need to get the row number of a selected row in the QTableWidget.
How do I get the number as an int?

How can I make the variable change with what row I'm clicking?

Comment: `QTableWidget.currentRow()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the variable based on the selected row, you can connect the signal [`QTableWidget.cellClicked(row, column)`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QTableWidget.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QTableWidget.cellClicked) to your own slot.

To get the currently selected row, use [`QTableWidget.currentRow()`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QTableWidget.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QTableWidget.currentRow):

```py
        # ...
        self.myTable.cellClicked.connect(self.getClickedCell)

    def getClickedCell(self, row, column):
        print('clicked!', row, column)
```

Comment: How can I connect the signal?
I tried `QTableWidget.cellClicked(row, column).connect()`

Comment: and yes, row and column are defined

Comment: Found out there is no need to define column and row... now it works, thanks for helping!